# wordpressをローカルの MAMP環境でみれる方法を探しています

Tags: wordpress, mamp

wordpressをローカル環境でみれる方法を探しています。

wordpress（php）ではないhtml,cssのファイルはMAMPでみることはできています。
wordpressをmanpにてローカル環境でみるためにやったこととしては....

・htdocs内にwordpressファイルを格納する
・MAMPのopen webstart pageにアクセスしてデータベースにwordpress作成

これ以前にphpの設定をMAMPで設定する必要があるのか？
そのMAMPで設定するやり方がよくわかりません。

詳しく理解したいため、おすすめの書籍やサイトを教えていただけるだけでも構いません。
ぜひ、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: そこまでできているのでしたら、あとは htdocsのWordPressのログイン画面にアクセスすれば、
インストーラーが動くはずですがその画面がでないということでしょうか？

Comment: MAMPであればhtdocs内にWordPressのファイル一式のディレクトリを配置してブラウザからそのディレクトリにアクセスすれば見れるはずですが。
質問者さんがどのような操作手順で見れていないのかがわからないです。